# Solve for a matrix "trapped in" summations?

Tags: matrices

I am trying to solve for matrix $X$ that is "trapped amid a summation."
$$\sum_{i}^N\left(XA_iX^TXA_i^T+XA_i^TX^TXA_i\right)-\sum_{i}^M\left(B_iX+B^T_iX\right)=0,$$

assuming matrix dimensions match nicely. In the latter summation, I can "rescue $X$ out of the summation," but not in the former...

I am a bit frustrated that I cannot even solve this, as it seems to be just a multivariate version of $ax+b=0$. What knowledge am I missing in solving for a matrix in an equation?

Comment: If you write entries for your matrices, you will end up with polynomail equations in several variables. Not sure it is possible to find a simple expression for the solutions (if any)... What do the $A_i$'s and $B_i$ look like?

Comment: At least for orthogonal matrices $X$ (i.e., $X^{-1}=X^T$) you have $X\sum_{i}^{N}(A_{i}A_{i}^{T}+A_{i}^{T}A_{i})-\left(\sum_{i}^{M}(B_{i}+B_{i}^{T})\right)X=0$ and consequently upon right multiplication by $X^T$, $X\left[\sum_{i}^{N}(A_{i}A_{i}^{T}+A_{i}^{T}A_{i})\right]X^T=\sum_{i}^{M}(B_{i}+B_{i}^{T})$ which is the case if and only if $\sum_{i}^{M}(B_{i}+B_{i}^{T})$ and $\sum_{i}^{N}(A_{i}A_{i}^{T}+A_{i}^{T}A_{i})$ are similar. Weakening this condition on $X$, I don't believe a solution for $X$ always exists.

Comment: @Taladris $A_i$ and $B_i$'s are formed in a quite complicated fashion so that I cannot see if they are any special. Let me think of a cleaner way of presenting them after I figure out how. If possible, could you hint me what properties of $A_i$ and $B_i$'s will simplify things?

Comment: @Taladris I agree eventually maybe I have to spell out all the entries to solve for $X$. May I check in this case how people usually do it? I find it quite a huge project to spell all entries out, and it confuses me very soon as I expand more and more...

Comment: @Nobody Thanks! But in my case, $X$ cannot be orthogonal, because my ultimate solution is actually covariance matrix, which I have decomposed to $X^TX$ so that the optimization becomes unconstrained ($X$ can be an arbitrary matrix). If $X$ is orthogonal, my eventual solution will be always $I$.